# I need help on duplicating Excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I am preparing a student report card. I have a sheet called (ENTRY) which contains the student's names in column and marks for the various subjects they wrote in corresponding rows like this:

[image: Starting sheet]

Now, I want to extract the information on this sheet by searching for the student's name and retrieve the other information base on the subject they wrote like in the second image.

[image: Report Card Generated]

Comment: I have  only used the vlookup function to reference the data one at a time and if i do that i have too many function. I want a macro which can do the work for me at once.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: i am new to macro. I only used functions and formulars through out